# Don't understand static boolean behavior

Tags: c++, static, header, boolean

I have a header file that has some static variables for all of my files to use. I have a boolean variable in there initialized to 0 -

```
//in utility.h
static bool read_mess = false;
```

that I want to change to true if --view-read-messages is in the command line arguments so that I can do something like this when I get a message from a client -

```
//code from a different file
if(UTILITY_H::read_mess)
    std::cout<<"\nMessage successfully received from Client 2: "<<in2;
```

In main, I check for the command line argument and set the variable, read_mess, to true -

```
//this is in a for, where temp is the command line arg[i]
else if(strcmp(temp.c_str(), "--view-read-messages") == 0) {
    UTILITY_H::read_mess = true;
}
```

I can print the value of read_mess after this line in main and it says that it is true. But when I'm checking if its true in the if statement I posted above, read_mess is back to false. Why does this happen? I'm sure its just something simple, but I can't seem to make it work. Are all of the variables in utility.h reinitialized each time I do UTILITY_H::? And if so, why?

Comment: Also, I moved the variable to a main static, but that had the same problem.

Comment: This might be stupid, but just to clarify this - are you sure that you are NOT doing 'if(UTILITY_H::read_mess = false) {}'?

Comment: This creates a static variable in *every* .cpp file that includes the header.  That's not what you want.  Use the *extern* keyword in the header and define the variable in one of the .cpp files.

Comment: @hans or `static`, but a class member.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`static` in this context means "local" (to the translation unit). There will be multiple copies of `read_mess` in your program, one per translation unit which is *not* the same thing as a header file. (In your case you can most likely approximate "translation unit" as .cpp or .c or .cc file).

Probably what you meant to do was to *declare* an `extern` variable, or `static` *class member* and *define* it in just one translation unit.

In practice using `extern` means in your header file you want to write:

```
extern bool read_mess;
```

But in *one and only one* other place that isn't a header:

```
bool read_mess = false;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. One question though - when I define the extern in a .cpp for a class, it works fine. But if I do that in main, it doesn't even compile (undefined references). Why is that?

Comment: I think you have another problem too - `UTILITY_H::` is *very* odd. I would usually assume that `UTILITY_H` is a guard macro. If it is then by chance what you have will work, but I would strongly recommend consulting a good book or possibly asking another question. See http://sscce.org/ for advice on how to write a good question though, good questions usually post *minimal* complete code that demonstrates the problem in question and some text that explains what the unexpected element was too.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a static variable in a header file an copy of the staic variable gets created  in each **[Translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)**(headers+source file) in which the file is included.

You are checking the value of the static variable which is a copy defined for that translation unit, it is not the same as the one you initialized in another translation unit.

You are better off using a `extern` if you want to access the variable across different files.

**utility.h** - Include this in all files where you want to access `read_mess`

```
extern bool read_mess;
```

**File1.cpp** - Define `read_mess` in one of the source files

```
#include"utility.h"

bool read_mess = false;
```

**File2.cpp** - Access `read_mess` in any of the source files

```
#include "utility.h"

if(read_mess)
{
    //do what interests you
}
```

---

Also,

**C++03 standard: 7.3.1.1/2 says:**

> The use of the static keyword is deprecated when declaring objects in a namespace scope, the **[unnamed-namespace](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc10unnamed_namespaces.htm)** provides a superior alternative.

Comment: re your flag:  There is nothing a mod can do about it.  keep an eye out, if they don't revert, you'll have to email team @ StackOverflow.  Only a dev can help you at that point.

Comment: To my knowledge the deprecation has been revoked in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

`static` global variables are privates to each .c or .cpp file (or translation unit). If you print out the address of `read_mess` (e.g., `printf("%x", &read_mess);`), you will see different addresses, which means two separate copies of the boolean variable exist.

A solution would be remove `static` keyword, or replace with `extern`. And, place the definition of that variable *only once* in any .c or .cpp file.